# Different behaviour for pdist and pdist2

Tags: matlab, distance, pdist

In a MATLAB code I am using the `kullback_leibler_divergence` dissimilarity function that can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39275-histogram-distances/content/kullback_leibler_divergence.m).

I have a matrix `A` and I compute the dissimilarity matrix using the downloaded function.

In theory, if I calculate

```
clear
A = rand(132,6); % input matrix
diss_mat = pdist(A,'@kullback_leibler_divergence'); % calculate the dissimilarity
square_diss_mat = squareform(diss_mat); % I put the dissimilarities in a square matrix
one_dist = pdist2(A(1,:),A,@kullback_leibler_divergence);
```

I should get the first row of `square_diss_mat` equal to `one_dist`, but I am not.

If I use the Euclidean distance I get it:

```
diss_mat = pdist(A);
square_diss_mat = squareform(diss_mat);
one_dist = pdist2(A(1,:),A);
```

Could you please tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `kullback_leibler_divergence` is not symmetric, thus the order matters:

```
one_dist = pdist2(A, A(1,:), @kullback_leibler_divergence);
```

I don't see any practical application using a non-symmetric function with `pdist` or `pdist2`.

Comment: sorry you are right! I was confused by the square_diss_mat that is symmetric

Comment: `pdist` assumes symmetric properties, evaluating only half of the matrix and copying the other half.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, the function says "Implementation of the Kullback-Leibler Divergence to use with pdist" is that an error then?

Comment: I don't see an application, but there might be one.